# unable to download files into into microsof Virtual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c#

Hello Everyone: I am unable to download files into Microsoft Virtual express 2013. By default they open in windows picture viewer and they never load. When I attempt to load into Microsoft Virtual Express 2013, it states "one or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. See output window for details." The output window states, " Project file could not be loaded. Could not find part of the path." Could anyone please advise? Thank you...

Comment: "Project file could not be loaded. Could not find part of the path." - you should figure out that part first (look at sln/csproj files in text editor of your choice).

Comment: Your path is wrong. It should be something like C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015 but it isn't. you have to figure out the right path.

Comment: One or more of the projects will have (unavaible) next to it. The file path property will tell you were it's looking for the project.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses...